# C# Button Shape issue

Tags: c#, button, draw

I recently tried to follow this tutorial [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aswBuf1qpTSAJ%3ahttp://en.csharp-online.net/Shaped_Button%2bc#%20shaped%20buttons&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&hl=ro&ct=clnk) but I don't really understand how it works. My problem is that I don't see any button like the in the image or anything like that, there is no button on my form.

Also [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8vid78nSpIQJ%3ahttp://en.csharp-online.net/Shaped_Button_Code%2bhttp://en.csharp-online.net/Shaped_Button_Code&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&hl=ro&ct=clnk)  is the full source code from the tutorial. I would like to know how to add the circle with the buttons on my form.

Thank you

Comment: Please debug, and try to work out where the code is going wrong. Then repost the malfunctioning code.

Comment: I browsed over your first link quickly and basically the tutorial is showing you how to override the paint event, there are plenty explanations around about what this does exactly

Comment: There is no problem with the code, my problem is that the buttons doesn't appear so maybe there is a spacial function to add the button to my Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it seems that you have not added this `Button` to your `Form`.

In your `Form` code behind in `constructor` add:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     var btn = new simonButton(); //create button
     this.Controls.Add(btn);      //add it to form, it will be positioned in location (0,0) top-left corner
}
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the idea. So this actually makes a new button class.

Answer (score 0):

If you've added the new button class and successfully compiled, then you should have the new button called "simonButton" appearing at the TOP of your ToolBox so you can add them to your form like any other control. Change the ForeColor() property through the IDE to change the color of the button.

[image: simonButton at the Top of the ToolBox]